# Intellij Idea Community Edition 10.5 - Configuring an application server

Tags: java, web-applications, intellij-idea, ide, sunone

Is it possible to run a web application using **Sun ONE application server 7** in **Intellij Idea Community Edition 10.5**?  I want to configure the server in IDE and run the application there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For running/debugging/deploying to application servers, you'll need the Ultimate Edition.

Having said that, with Community Edition you can configure an external tool "File > Settings > Tools > External Tools", which is basically a shortcut from the IDE to your application server and runs it in a console in the IDE.